# Ripple emulator giving 404 for local file

Tags: html, blackberry, ripple

I creates c:\Users\Me\RippleSites\test\index.html, enabled 'allow access to file URLS' in the Chrome extension, started the Ripple server and enabled the emulator. I tried navigating to `http://localhost:9910/test/index.html` but am only getting a 404 error. What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I just formatted and forgot to enable to known file extensions in Windows Explorer. When I saved index.html it added .txt

Comment: Don't use Windows Explorer